# In the context of Laplace transforms, what does the subscript in $h(t) = f(t)\cdot u_3(t)$ signify?

Tags: notation, laplace-transform

**Problem**

Note: I do not need help solving this problem (yet), but I'm unsure about notation.

*Find the Laplace tranform of the function* $h(t) = e^{2(t-3)}u_3(t)$.

**Question**

What does the subscripted $3$ in $u_3(t)$ mean?

Comment: It likely means $u(t-3)$, the unit step function shifted $3$ units to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dr. MV suggested in the comment, it referred to the right-shifted unit step function.

$u_3(t) = \begin{cases} 
      0, & t < 3 \\
      1, & t \geq 3 
   \end{cases}
$

*Posting this as an answer for the sake of completeness.*